# How can use asp.net mvc identity tables in asp.net mvc core indentity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I've asp.net MVC project that using EF Code First and asp.net MVC Identity for authentication, so now I want to create another website by asp.net core MVC and asp.net core MVC Identity. actually, I want to these websites work by the same database, is it possible? Considering the asp.net MVC identity tables are different by asp.net core MVC tables.

Comment: Possible - yes. You'll have to share connection string and have the same DB models

Comment: yes, I know about that, but the point is asp.net identity tables are different by asp.net core identity.